# Redirect and losing <head> contents

Tags: javascript, php, css

My current page in question is set to automatically redirect and have the URL include '?s='. For some reason this makes part of the web page work and I find it easiest, however, now that I've added this to the top of my page:

```
if(!strpos(curPageURL(), 's=')) {
header('LOCATION: http://games.thanetdragons.co.uk/killingfloor/?s=');}
```

In this instance it is found and when it is, forwards correctly, but for some reason it completely removes all the contents of anything prior to the `body` tag.

In case you would like to view this yourself please go [here](http://games.thanetdragons.co.uk/killingfloor/).

You can also view the entire contents of this page [here](http://pastebin.com/3mV9Cukt).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not seeing what you are seeing.  In Safari 7 on MAC OS X, I see all of the content.  However, I do get two errors about 'HTTPS' being an undefined index.

Comment: Look at the source code. There is absolutely nothing in the `<head>` section. It's not even registering the DOCTYPE. It loads everything else fine as it pushes the ajax through fine which allows you to see the content. Just not the styles or anything in the `head` section. Reason there is style is because I added an external link, it was all in the same file.